# Density argument to show derivations on $C^0_0(\mathbb{R^n})$ are 0.

Tags: differential-geometry

It is a classic homework question to show that the only derivation on the germ of continuous functions of $\mathbb{R^n}$ at 0, $C_0^0(\mathbb{R^n})$ is the 0 deriviation.  I want to know if this can be done via a density argument.  If $\delta$ is a derivation on $C_0^0(\mathbb{R^n})$, then $\delta([x_i])=0$ since $x_i=|x_i|^{\frac{1}{2}} \times sgn(x_i) |x_i|^{\frac{1}{2}}$.  This implies $\delta=0$ on any polynomial.

I can improve this.  For $[f] \in C_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$, I can write $\delta f(x)=\delta f(0)+\delta \langle x,\int_0^1 \nabla f(tx) dt\rangle=0$ because $\delta([x_i])=0$. Thus $\delta=0$ on $C_0^1(\mathbb{R^n})$

Is there a density argument that one can use to show that $\delta=0$ on $C^0_0(\mathbb R^n)$?